# How to create a common components in flux?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, flux

I use Flux build my app,and there a question confuse me:"How to create a common components in flux?".

First, the "common components" is mean a components like the "Like button" at Facebook, not only one  project use this.

And the components has "Store","Action","View(react component)",the "Store" exports a "dispatchToken" for the app's Dispatcher.But the "Action" part,it need require a Dispatcher,and use like "Dispather.handleViewAction".
But in the components's context,we don't know what is the Dispatcher.

In your app,how do you create a common components?Or do you know how the Facebook's group create it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, common components should not depend on `actionCreators`. You can define callbacks in the parent component and call them from the common component ( via `this.props` ). Those callback functions can call `actionCreators` afterwards:

Parent app specific component:

```
render : 

   <CommonButton  onClick={ this.onCommonButtonClick } >


onCommonButtonClick:

   MyActionCreator.createAction(...);
```

CommonButton :

```
render :

  <button onClick={ this.props.onClick }>
```